# Clear elements which are in the middle of the 3 column layout

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns

a have three column layout and i want to have three divs inside the middle column, but every time my content in sidebars is "longer" than content in the middle div, boxes just jump down under "the longest div". Here is my code:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 15%; background-color: yellow;">
<p>left</p>
<p>left</p>
<p>left</p>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 15%; background-color: pink;">
<p>right</p>
<p>right</p>
<p>right</p>
<p>right</p>
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;">
<div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%; background-color: blue; margin: 1%">
    middle
</div>
```

​

Here is code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyHGP/1/) for better understanding. I would be glad if somebody could explain "clearing" to me.

**Edit:**
I followed this tutorial http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0406.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middle div is being presented as a block level element and is why is being pushed along with the content of your sidebar divs. Float it to the left and add a proper width to it to fix the issue. Middle div width = 20% + 20% margin +  15% + 15% sidebar widths = 70% + 30% middle div = 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/DyHGP/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the following, which you have after every three divs.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Clearing is used to drop an elementy right under anything that is float. Using clear: both; means that it will clear anything that is floated left or right.

A quick fix would be to remove those elements and increase the width of each of the divs in the centre column to 30% which would then force the 4th one onto the next line.

Comment: Ok, this I understand. I just thought that this is proper way to to this (added tutorial which I followed), but as I can see, it does not work when other floating elements are present. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The tutorial works because they are the columns themselves and then they are split into rows. Being the same height also makes it easy, but columns within columns are a pain!